# Typescript JSON How do I read JSON using hierarchical key like "appInsights:instrumentationKey"

Tags: json, angular

Given the below JSON, I should be able to read the JSON using hierarchical key path such as "appInsights:instrumentationKey". How can i do this in an angular project?

```
{
    "appInsights": {
        "instrumentationKey": "<dev-guid-here>"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
const obj = JSON.parse('your json');
const val1 = obj.appInsights.instrumentationKey;
const val2 = obj['appInsights'].instrumentationKey;
```

UPDATE: Will has fair point. If your JSON data doesnt contain user input e.g won't contain anything harmful that will execute in browser then

```
const val = eval('obj.' + keyPath.replace(/:/g, '.'));
```

or if you use Lodash: [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

Comment: This approach requires knowing the property names ahead of time, and does not answer the hierarchical key path element.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```js
getJsonProperty(jsonObj, keyPath: string) {
  const keys: string[] = keyPath.split(':');
  return jsonObj[keys[0]][keys[1]];
}
```

If you don't know how many levels the object can have, you could write a switch statement with cases for each accepted length of the `keys` Array. Obviously that means hard-coding each case (and a fixed maximum number of possible levels), unless there's some other way of using string literals I'm forgetting.